# Need help understanding weird RegionUnion behavior

Tags: regions, geometry

I'm trying to understand some weird behaviors of `RegionUnion` in a small piece of code. In particular,

1. `RegionUnion` is not commutative.
2. `RegionUnion` truncates regions, seemingly arbitrarily.
3. `RegionUnion` introduces strange artifacts.

Here is the code I'm working on.

```
a = 6;
simplex = ImplicitRegion[x1 + x2 + x3 == a && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0 && x3 >= 0, {x1, x2, x3}];
p1 = ImplicitRegion[2 x1 - x2 - x3 + 3 == 0 , {x1, x2, x3}];
p2 = ImplicitRegion[-x1 + 2 x2 - x3 + 3 == 0 , {x1, x2, x3}];
Region[RegionUnion[p1, simplex]]
```

As written, this produces roughly what I would expect. The simplex is truncated weirdly, but maybe that's because it's hitting the bounding box or something. However, there are several small changes that cause this program to fail:

- Replacing the first line by `a=8` gives a range error.
- Reversing the order of the arguments in the last line gives a totally different image.
- Replacing the `p1` in the last line by `p2` results in weird, jagged artifacts.

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like getting the union of two planes shouldn't be very hard, and it certainly shouldn't depend on the order in which you supply the arguments.

Comment: Just to clarify: don't confuse the actual region with what `Region` shows you.  You are working with symbolic regions, and all the results are fine.  Where things get problematic is how these results are visualized by `Region`.  But `Region` visualizes only for preview purposes (it does not change the region in any way). If you are serious about visualization/discretization, use BoundaryDiscretizeRegion, DisretizeRegion, RegionPlot, RegionPlot3D.  These won't solve your problems immediately, but at least they have several options to tweak how the region is discretized/visualized.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like DiscretizeRegion gets me most of the way there.